# Error Analyzing App Version - Apple submit to store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am facing issue since morning as below
Error Analyzing App Version

It is seem issue from apple side.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599#705599021

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely an Apple issue. You may also get an error referring to rate limiting if you try to export from the command line using `xcodebuild` instead.

Workaround I saw on the Apple forums was to turn off Wi-Fi temporarily https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599?answerId=712953022#712953022